# How do I use Sinatra and Sequel to get an array from a checkbox HTML form?

Tags: html, ruby, forms, checkbox, sinatra

Here's my form:

```
<form action="/results" method="post" name="checkbox_form">
    <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="Bacon">Bacon (1 lb., sliced)<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="Eggs (dozen)">Eggs (1 dozen)
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

If the user checks off both the 'Bacon' and 'Eggs (1 dozen)' boxes, how do I use Sinatra and/or Sequel to return this array:

```
["Bacon","Eggs (dozen)"]
```

As you can see, the array elements are the form's 'value' elements.

As a side question: How does Sinatra treat checkbox forms anyway? I couldn't find any good info in the Sinatra manual.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't actually need Sequel to *receive* an item from a `post` request. Sequel is a database, so you would save the returned item to the database after receiving it from your `post`. So, you don't actually need it in order to return an array in this case.

Also, forms and checkboxes are not specific to Sinatra but *are* specific to HTML.

When you submit the form as a `post` request, it is sent back to the server and Sinatra where it can be handled. Sinatra provides a `params` method which contains a hash of the values of the form that was submitted.

In the example below, I use a special syntax (`item[]`) to provide the values named `item` as an array within the params hash. For example, this is what the params hash returns `{"item"=>["Bacon", "Eggs (dozen)"]}` with both checkboxes checked.

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/results' do
  erb :results
end
post '/results' do
   params[:item].inspect
end

__END__

@@ results
<form action="/results" method="post" name="checkbox_form">
    <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="Bacon">Bacon (1 lb., sliced)<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="Eggs (dozen)">Eggs (1 dozen)<br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate"/>
</form>
```

The `get` block receives a get request from a user's browser and handles it. In this example, it returns an HTML form to the user.

The `post` block receives a post request from a user's browser after they have submitted the form. The user is shown the response from the server which in this case is an array of the checkbox values.